# Array from foreach php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am using this to create an array:

```
foreach($results as $tire){
            $group_price[] = array($tire->group, $tire->price);
        }
```

My results are:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => MAXAT 
        [1] => 118.91 
        ) 
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => FZSUV 
        [1] => 137.81 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => MAXAT 
        [1] => 153.79 
    )
)
```

What I would like my results to be:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [group] => MAXAT 
        [price] => 118.91
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [group] => FZSUV 
        [price] => 137.81
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [group] => MAXAT 
        [price] => 153.79
    )
)
```

I am just not sure how to change my foreach in a way that would change the output.

Comment: Change it to `$group_price[] = array('group' => $tire->group, 'price' => $tire->price);` inb4 incoming repster

Comment: 4 answers in less than 30 secounds, we good or what ;-)

Comment: It's a very basic beginner's question, Dagon. Easy points...

Comment: `(array)$tire` may also work :)

Comment: some of us don't do this for the points :-)

Comment: Yes, easy points, very easy question, speed was scored :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Like so:**

```
foreach($results as $tire){
    $group_price[] = array(
        'group' => $tire->group,
        'price' => $tire->price
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
foreach($results as $tire){
            $group_price[] = array('group' => $tire->group,'price' => $tire->price);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like so:

```
foreach($results as $tire){
     $group_price[] = array(
                            'group' => $tire->group,
                            'price' => $tire->price
                           );
}
```

Add keys to your array elements, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($results as $tire){
            $group_price[] = array('group'=>$tire->group, 'price'=>$tire->price);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
array('group' => $tire->group, 'price' => $tire->price);
```